# Node.js async/await try catch flow - best practice

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I moved to `async/await` from `promises` lately. However, I'm uncertain about the `try...catch` right flow. I have the following example:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

const func2 = async () => {
    const response1 = await rp('http://nodejs.org/dist/index.json');
    if (response1) {
      return await rp('http://headers.jsontest.com'); // #opt 1: return a value
      // return rp('http://headers.jsontest.com'); // #opt 2: return a promise:
    }
}

(func1 = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await func2();
    console.log('Success!');
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('Failed!');
  }
})();
```

I was wondering if I should add `try...catch` to `func2`, but I came to conclusion it's already being handled in the `try...catch` of `func1`.

**Is this code valid?**

Comment: Yes it's valid, but this is a highly opinionated and contextual question. It also depends on what exceptions you expect to see at `func2` and how you want to react to them. For example you might immediately want to handle an exception inside `func2` so that you could retry/recover and still return a valid response to the caller.

Comment: can you have the situation where `response1` is "falsey" but there's no error thrown? because in that case `response` would be `undefined` - is that valid?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this code valid?

Yes. *(In terms of the `try`/`catch` aspect, see "side note" below.)*

> I was wondering if I should add `try...catch` to `func2`, but I came to conclusion it's already being handled in the `try...catch` of `func1`.

Yes, it is. Just like with non-`async` functions, you only need the `try`/`catch` in `func2` if you want to handle the error there (entirely, or partially and then (re)throwing). If you don't, allow it to propagate to the caller. Just ensure it's handled *somewhere*.

---

Side note: I'm assuming your `func2` has a `return` in the case where `response1` is a falsy value. If not, `func2`'s promise's resolution value will be `undefined` in that case.

---

Side note 2: I'm guessing you've added the `func1 =` part there just to give yourself a name to refer to in the question and it's not in your real code. But in case it is: Unless you've declared it somewhere you haven't shown, in your example `func1` is an implicit global. Recommend avoiding those. :-) More in my blog post: [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)

---

Side note 3 *(he does go on a bit, doesn't he?)*: If you're not using `func1` anywhere else (just using it as a wrapper for convenient `await` use within it), if you want to, you can avoid a level of indentation by using the fact that `async` functions return promises:

```
(async () => {
  const response = await func2();
  console.log('Success!');
})().catch(e => {
  console.log('Failed!');
});
```

The up side is that it's a bit more concise. The downside is that it mixes metaphors. :-) That and the `try`/`catch` do **exactly** the same thing, it's purely a matter of how you prefer to write it, which is entirely up to you.

Comment: @LukeStoward: I just removed that parenthetical, it doesn't add anything. (In the *general* case, I disagree with you, but that opinion aspect doesn't need to come into the answer anyway, so... :-) )

Comment: I appreciate that, I guess it's a matter of whether you like to fail fast and fail loud or not. :)

Comment: @LukeStoward: You're failing fast and loud either way.

Comment: @iT.J.Crowder for the **"side note"**  if resolving the the site url will fail it will catch, otherwise it will get some value. I can't see when it will be `undefined`. P.S. This example is just for the sake of example.

Comment: @wizard: If the first line of your function will either throw (reject) or return a truthy value, then there's no need for the `if` at all. A throw (rejected promise) will exit `func2` prior to the `if`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder your'e right. however in which case it will return `undefined` ?

Comment: @wizard: If `response1` is a falsy value. Either it can be falsy, in which case that code returns (resolves) `undefined`, or it can't be falsy, in which case the `if` statement doesn't make sense.